# Netbeans crashes with error: Loadlibrary failed with error 126: the specified module could not be found

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans crashes after a while with error:

Loadlibrary failed with error 126: the specified module could not be found

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling netbeans and java. I also tried few solutions posted earlier for this error, but its still not working.

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Operating System.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your graphics adapter from ATI? If yes, then have a look at this: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/64674-loadlibrary-failed-error-126-a.html

Comment: I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: I've solved this, look at my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996959/pyinstaller-failing-to-find-sdl2-when-creating-an-exe-for-a-python-kivy-program

Answer (score 1):

I tried the previous answer as well but it didn't work. I think the above was pretty much right but what worked for me was that I had to uninstall my AMD driver and reinstall it for this to resolve. It must have been a bad dll or something.

1. right click start
2. select device manager
3. from display adapter
4. right click AMD Radeon(TM) graphics
5. select uninstall
6. make sure Delete the driver software for this device
7. click uninstall

uninstalled driver then either wait or restart for it to download the new driver. not really an elegant solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a missing dll or broken uninstall from AMD drivers. Try this:

1. Run CMD as administrator
2. type: cd /d C:/Windows/System32
3. for 32bit type: copy atioglxx.dll .dll
4. for 64bit type: copy atio6axx.dll .dll

If you are running Windows 7 you might need this code for 64bit systems

copy atio6axx.dll atiogl64.dll

Also you could use CCleaner or similar to remove all traces of AMD drivers and reinstall your video drivers.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and this didn't work for me