# pyinstaller failing to find sdl2 when creating an exe for a python kivy program

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an EXE file for my kivy app, and I'm using pyinstaller to make that happen. I've tried to write pyinstaller programName.py, and also used '-w' & '-f', but it results in writing INFO: Window: Provider: sdl2, and then a popup appears with the following text: "LoadLibrary failed with error 126: Tge specified module could not be found".

I also tried to create a small hello world program, where it worked fine (my guess is that there was no use for sdl2). also tried to reinstall pyinstaller.

EDIT:
does same thing when the python file is run, which it didn't months ago

Answer (score 0):

turns out that disabling AMD Radeon(TM) Grahpics under Display Adapters in device manager works. not sure why, but maybe this can help others though.

Credit to Theta Box: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQCt6uDrFRM